# allowed_types tud not support by Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to upload .tud file type by codeigniter3 upload library. `$configs['allowed_types']='tud|png';` Png only allowd but not tud. when try to upload tud file, It shows error that

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: You must to define MIME-type for this file extension in **application/config/mimes.php**

Comment: Thanks, I added type in MIME and it's works for me